# cv::FileStorage writing double with precision

Tags: c++, opencv, precision

If I have the code:

```
cv::FileStorage fs("foo.yaml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "myval" << 0.6;
```

I end up with:

```
myval: 5.9999999999999998e-01
```

Of course, I know [why floating point isn't exact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/1270789), but for the sake of neatness in the file I would like to see one of:

```
myval: 6.00e-01
```

or:

```
myval: 0.60
```

A work-around is:

```
std::stringstream floatFormat;
floatFormat << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 0.6;
fs << "myval" << floatFormat.str();
```

But that gives:

```
myval: "0.60"
```

Which is of `string` type.

Is there any way I can force OpenCV to use a specified precision when writing values?

<sup>Note, this is a file I consume myself, so I can tweak my reading code to use `std::stof()` on the fly, but it would nice to have a cleaner solution.</sup>

Comment: Have you considered to use some kind of fix point arithmetic instead? In the simplest case, that might be an integral type with a respectively tweaked stream I/O. It's hard to say without knowing what `0.6` represents in your case (i.e. which range with which precision has to be covered).

Comment: @Scheff This number is a scaling factor rather than a money value.

Comment: I did some research and I think it is not possible. I even tried converting your value to a `cv::Mat` and limit the precision with `cv::Formatter`. That works for the `std::cout but` not for the `cv::FileStorage`. I think the best you can do is format to string like you did and read it again as a float.

Comment: 0.6 is double 0.6f is float. May be it will help.